# Print pyramid of number with pattern

Tags: for-loop, go

This is the pyramid number pattern that I want to build

```
          1   
        2   2   
      3   4   3   
    4   5   5   4   
  5   6   7   6   5
```

This is what I tried, I can only make it to have the correct shape, I don't know how to make it to have the correct pattern

```
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    for j := i; j <= 5; j++ {
        fmt.Print("  ")
    }
    for j := 0; j < i; j++ {
        fmt.Print(i, "   ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Output:

```
          1   
        2   2   
      3   3   3   
    4   4   4   4   
  5   5   5   5   5
```

Comment: The homework is to get you to look for the pattern, how are `i` and `j` both related to the output?

Comment: @Jim could you kindly give me a suggestion on how to learn to recognize a pattern and implements it on programming?

Comment: There's lots of ways to format it, but the key is to see the relationship between the indexes here. Think of the cases you need to cover; counting up to the halfway point, counting back down, the line ending, etc. https://go.dev/play/p/xLXKO973-16